# Sub import issues with tkinter messagebox

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox, python-idle

I'm writing a GUI application with tkinter, now I wanted to use the messageboxes that tkinter has built in, so I figured since I already have tkinter imported (as tk) it would just be `tk.messagebox.showerror()` but this more or less worked...

I when running this through IDLE it worked with no issues but if I use `python <module-name>.py` in the terminal it throws an AttributeError.

Here is the simplest sample I could make:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.messagebox.showerror(title="Test Error", message="This is a test")
root.mainloop()
```

Now to make things even stranger if I add `from tkinter import messagebox` as an import than this same code works when run from the terminal (keeping the `tk.messagebox.showerror`). Obviously it must still be viewed as an attribute of tkinter so why doesn't it work without the explicit import?

I guess I'm not really looking for solution as such (since I found some way to make it work) but more an explanation of why this is happening.

And as always any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Starting  with 3.5.3 and 3.6.a4, "import tkinter; tkinter.message' will raise the appropriate AttributeError when run by IDLE.

Comment: My answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806673/importing-from-a-package-in-idle-vs-shell/38808437#38808437 describes how to fix this in existing releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has arisen before in the form of "Why does `import tkinter; tkinter.font` works in IDLE but not in python itself?"  The explanation is the interaction between how `import` works and how IDLE currently sets up the subprocess where it executes your code.

IMPORT: sys.modules is a dictionary that maps module names to imported module objects.  At a high-level, `import modname` is equivalent to the following.

```
if modname not in sys.modules:
    sys.modules[modname] = module(modname)
modname = sys.modules[modname]
```

For a python-coded package, the module is created from `modname/__init__.py`.  Importing a package does not import its submodules.  Which is to say, it does not run `modname/submodule.py`.  Subsequently importing a submodule adds the submodule to sys.modules and to the package as an attribute.  Importing the module after that binds the existing module, which has a submodule as an attribute, to the name specified.

IDLE: Currently when IDLE sets up a subprocess for running your code, it directly or indirectly imports tkinter and its submodules.  (The code is in idlelib/run.py and the idlelib modules it imports.) This can be seen by running

```
for name in sys.modules:
    if name.startswith('tkinter'):
        print(name)
```

when IDLE starts. So, when you run `import tkinter`, it is the second tkinter import in the process, and the name `'tkinter'` is bound to the existing tkinter module that has submodules as attributes

Solution: A purpose of IDLE is to develop code that runs in python itself.  It is a bug for IDLE to run buggy code that will not run in python.  I am working on [refactoring idlelib](https://bugs.python.org/issue25507) so that the above will not print anything.  The only tkinter module ever needed is tkinter.messagebox and that is only needed if there is a problem that prevents running your code.  So importing `messagebox` can be delayed until it is needed, which is very seldom.